# Mark selections in Vim

Tags: vim, plugins, selection, shortcut

I sometime dream of a mark-selection feature in Vim, just like when you type:

```
ma
```

in normal mode, you can then hit, from anywhere:

```
`a
```

to get back to this place `a`.
I wish there were something like:

```
ma
```

in *visual* mode. This would save your visually selected area. And you would just type then, from any place in normal mode:

```
<someHeader>a
```

to enter visual mode back with this `a` selection.

Is there such a feature in Vim? Or an extension that looks like? Or an easy way to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the kind solution of [Steven Hall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31303126), along with some modifications I needed for the visual marks not to overwrite regular registers.

https://github.com/iago-lito/vim-visualMarks

It is a small vimScript allowing one to mark a visually selected area by typing, in *visual* mode:

```
ma
```

(for mark `a`)

Then retrieve it later from any place by typing, in *normal* mode:

```
<a
```

It does still need some basic improvements, but now anyone can try, improve and share. Thank you Steven for having launched the process :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly certain there isn't any way to name selections similar to how marks or registers can be referenced.

The closest feature that I can think of is the `gv` command which enters Visual mode with the *last* previously selected block already re-selected. I find this to be a lot more convenient than having to manually re-selecting the same block of text more than once.

---

It should be possible to write a function using Vimscript that saves the start and ends of a visual block as marks that can be re-used to reselect a Visual block. I had a look to see if it was possible to use Vimscript to save the `<` and `>` marks as other (less ephemeral) marks but I didn't see anything.

Comment: Yep, I know this one. But it is dramatically unique and quickly overwritten. I wish there were also something more persistent. Do you think it is worth developping something? Shouldn't be that hard with a few marks and some coordinates one would store in memory (at least) for each of them.

Comment: @Iago-lito I've just updated my answer. I also upvoted your question since I think it's a good one and I'd be interested in other answers.

Answer (score 2):

I have written this which I believe is what you are asking for:

```
function! VisualMark()
  call inputsave()
  let registers = input("m")
  call inputrestore()
  exec "normal! `<m" . registers[0]
  exec "normal! `>m" . registers[1]
endfun

function! GetVisualMark()
  call inputsave()
  let registers = input("`")
  call inputrestore()
  exec "normal! `" . registers[0]
  if strlen(registers) > 1
    exec "normal! v`" . registers[1]
  endif
endfun

vnoremap m <esc>:call VisualMark()<cr>
nnoremap ` :call GetVisualMark()<cr>
```

they should behave in the same way as a regular mark except only in visual mode, and they both need two arguments.

First, to get a visually selected area saved, in visual mode with the block selected, hit the m key like you normally would. It will then let you type in some more text... here the function will expect 2 characters which are the two registers that the beginning and end marks will be saved to... so for example entering mab in visual mode and then pressing enter (I could not figure out a way to make it work without an enter), would create a mark in register a for the beginning of the block, and b would be the end of the block.

To reselect the block visually, go to visual mode and do the ` which is the same as a regular mark... this too will expect two characters

**EDIT**:

I have made the implementation better in my opinion. Before I had it so that to bring back the visually selected block you had to be in visual mode then hit the backtick (same button that you would use for a normal mark) button and then the 2 registers. Now you do it in normal mode... This means that the default use of the backtick now uses this function, but the function now checks how many registers you provide... so if you only use one register, it will only take you back to that one. if you provide 2 registers, then it will visually select them... if you provide more than 2, it will only use the first 2.

The enter key is still required to enter in your selection though. It is probably better this way with the new implementation anyways.

For those that want to see, or use the old implementation this is it:

```
function! VisualMark()
  call inputsave()
  let registers = input("m")
  call inputrestore()
  exec "normal! `<m" . registers[0]
  exec "normal! `>m" . registers[1]
endfun

function! GetVisualMark()
  call inputsave()
  let registers = input("`")
  call inputrestore()
  exec "normal! `" . registers[0]
  exec "normal! v`" . registers[1]
endfun

vnoremap m <esc>:call VisualMark()<cr>
vnoremap ` <esc>:call GetVisualMark()<cr>
```

Comment: Wow! I just test tested that and it works. What an impressive first post! Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: And thanks for the idea as well... I made that implementation just for this post. Never thought of having it before but now I do, so it seems we both got something we can use out of this :)

Comment: I edited the above implementation... see the edit above. now to bring back the selection, you do not need to be in visual mode... after using it for a few hours moving my hand back and forth from the v to the ` got kind of repetitive, so now you can do it in normal mode.

Any improvements, suggestions, or questions about my code above are welcome.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for this fast and neat implementation! :) I only have a regret that the selection marks overwrite the regular ones, but I feel like we could fix it. Yet I'm trying to work on it. ;)

Comment: Got it! See my own answer.. Would you like to start developping it into something? :)

Comment: Would have posted this under your answer but I need a 50 rep to do that :) I agree it would be better without pressing enter. I initially tried that but vim kept throwing me errors. If someone else can get it to work that would be great, if not I can try again, but lets see if we can get it working as you want it first... I will spend some time thinking about this and I will let you know if I come up with something.

Comment: What I was thinking is have a new file called visual-marks or something, and have the function save a letter and the 4 coordinates. The problem is that you would need to have a way to then determine what marks are for what files. You could have different sections in this file for different files so that it can be searched, but this could result in a fairly large file in the future. If anyone has any better ideas I am all ears. I will continue to think of something else.

Comment: If it helps for anyone, to get an input without needing to press enter, use getchar()... problem with that is it returns a number, so usually you would do nr2char(getchar()) and that returns the character... so having something like "let c = nr2char(getchar())" will take a users input for a character and return it to the variable c.